# Javascript animation moving across the screen

Tags: javascript, animation, settimeout

Just new to animation. Required some help. I hope you could help. I've been struggling for days trying to understand how to do the following basic thing. don't know where i'm making a mistake. In fact, I've just managed to do a ball bounce with 25 balls. but this one is a little tricky. I was trying to use `setTimeout()` for some reason cannot get it going.

I just need 2 small squares moving across the screen horizontally, but it should be one behind the other. so basically the first square appears to the left, starts moving across the screen, then after 3 seconds the second one appears and simply  follows the first. Could you help. I'd be grateful. Thanks

Comment: Hey Ruben, could you provide us with some code, or examples of what you've tried so far? That'll help us help you better.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to do this?
With a `<canvas></canvas>`
Or just with a square marked `position: absolute;`
If it the second option, use a `<div></div>` and apply a `width` and an `height` in css. Making it `position: absolute;` and after use `left` and `top` properties. To move it, use `animation` or `@keyframes`.

Answer (score 0):

var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext('2d');

var Width=document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var Height=document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    var myarray=["sq1","sq2","sq3","sq4","sq5","sq6","sq7","sq8","sq9"];
    var temp= new Array(0);
    var coox=0;

        function rect(coox)
        {
            this.coox=coox;
        }

    for (x=0;x